# URL Rewrite in IIS7 Regular expression Pattern

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, iis-7

I want a URL pattern for the following  where :

this

http://www.test.com/xyz_number.jpg?vin=xyz&date=31052012

will be redirected to :

http://www.test.com/xyz/31052012/xyz_number.jpg

NOTE:  Here xyz_number and date value are dynamic which will be changing for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regular expression will perform the match:

```regex
^http://www.test.com/([^.]*).jpg\?vin=([^&]*)&date=(\d*)$
```

And the following expression will do the replacement:

```regex
http://www.test.com/$2/$3/$1.jpg
```

You don't say whether you're doing this in an ASP.NET HTTP Handler, or in an IIS module, but hopefully, this will give you a start.